# Docker and Linux architecture,var directory

Tags: linux, docker, fhs

I worked on Docker and Jenkins project and Now I am looking at `/var` directory of the docker container named `jenkins`

```
docker exec jenkins ls -l var
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Aug 26  2015 backups
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root    4096 Oct 14  2015 cache
drwxr-xr-x 12 jenkins jenkins 4096 Apr 13 09:03 jenkins_home
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root    4096 Apr 13 08:14 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root    staff   4096 Aug 26  2015 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root       9 Sep  7  2015 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root    4096 Oct 14  2015 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root    mail    4096 Sep  7  2015 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Sep  7  2015 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root       4 Sep  7  2015 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Sep  7  2015 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root    4096 Aug 26  2015 tmp
```

What does `/var` serve for?
I read at Linux tutorials site that `/var` is specific for each computer; that is, it is not shared over a network with other computers.In case of Docker swarm we have multiple containers,that need to communicate. Can someone explain more how all this functions?